# Call a method of a running process

Tags: c#

If i am know the address of a method that i want to call in an another process (C++), how can i do it in C#?

The offset of the method is always same.

My current code is:

```
struct DataToPass
{
   int field;
}

delegate void Caller(DataToPass data);

public void Call()
{
    DataToPass data = new DataToPass();
    data.field = 12345;

    IntPtr callptr = new IntPtr(myprocess.Modules[0].BaseAddress.ToInt32() + 0x3A5582);
    Caller call = (Caller)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(callptr, typeof(Caller));
    call(data);
}
```

But when i run the program i get an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in testcall.exe

Comment: Are you trying to write a virus in C#? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @oleksii C# viruses are the latest hot trend, I guess.

Comment: I wrote a small helper client to a game for our game server. I modified some values (vehicle setups, etc.) but i have to call a function in the game to recalculate the new values.

Comment: @user2759203 Do you need the game that is already running to calculate these values? Or can you calculate these values in a separate process?

Answer (score 6):

You are geting the address of the method in the remote process and trying to call whatever happens to be in the same address in your process. You're actually lucky you got an AccessViolation.

First you have to decide if the method should run in the calling process or the remote one. If it's supposed to run in the calling process then it's easier to just reference the DLL/EXE where the method resides and call it. But if you want it to run in the remote process you can use some form of remoting such as WCF.